# Jquery alway get value on first image from a list of images wrapped inside div

Tags: jquery

I need to get the image `src` value from list of image wrapped inside `div` and pass that value to a textbox.

I have worked on this example but it always get the value of first image irrespective of which image you click one.

http://jsfiddle.net/FMW22/

How do i modify script so that it always get the `src` of the image which is click to that textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your selector is on `#imgListContainer`, and selects the image using `$(this).find("img")`.

You need to change your selector to `#imgListContainer img`, and your `img` declaration to just `$(this)`.

---

Change your code to:

```
$(document).on("click", "#imgListContainer img", function(){
    var img = $(this), // select images inside .container
        len = img.length; // check if they exist
    if( len > 0 ){
        // images found, get id
        var attrID = img.attr("src"); // get id of first image
       // alert(attrID);
        $("#Text1").val(attrID);
    } else {
        // images not found
    }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FMW22/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "img", function(){
    $("#Text1").val($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: Why to use `document` if you have static `<div>` container`?

Comment: @VisioN Because then you have to wrap it in a document ready handler or put the script after the body.

Comment: Isn't it better to have `#imgListContainer img` instead of `img`?

Comment: @VisioN If the script is run in the `head`, `#imgListContainer` isn't loaded, so you can't attach event listeners to it, right? :P

Comment: @Asad :D Yeah, and then you need to bind click event to aaaaaaall images in the page, and then each time to bubble up to document element to get the event :)

Comment: @VisioN So you need to either do this:  `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code goes here*/})`, or put the script tag at the end of the body. The code above doesn't have this limitation. The click event isn't bound to `aaaaaaall images in the page`, it isn't even bound to one. It is bound to the document, which checks that the event target matches the selector before running the code.

Comment: @Asad The reasoning sounds weird :) It is always better to execute jQuery procedures on loaded DOM.

Comment: @VisioN Event delegation for elements that don't exist in the DOM at the time of script execution is a pretty common practice, actually. The "jQuery procedure" *is* being executed on a loaded part of the DOM, i.e. the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simpler:

```
$("#imgListContainer").on("click", "img", function() {
    $("#Text1").val(this.src);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FMW22/2/